# Am I correct that strcmp is equivalent (and safe) for literals?

Tags: c, strcmp

We all know the trouble overflows can cause, and this is why strn* exist - and most of the time they make sense. However, I have seen code which uses strncmp to compare commandline parameters like so:

```
if(... strncmp(argv[i], "--help", 6) == 0
```

Now, I would have thought that this is unnecessary and perhaps even dangerous (for longer parameters it would be easy to miscount the characters in the literal).

strncmp stops on nulls, and the code already assumes argv[i] is null-terminated. Any string literal is guaranteed to be null-terminated, so why not use strcmp?

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I've seen this a few times and this time it intrigued me enough to ask.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

yes it is perfectly safe and considered standard practice. String literals are **guaranteed** to be properly null terminated.

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure that the code is not intended to match on 
`"--helpmedosoemthingwithareallylongoptionname"`?

Comment: This seems like a distinct possibility.

Comment: that's a very good point. I don't *think* so in this case since all commandline args are done this way

Comment: The more likely intent was to match things like `--help=foobar`, but unfortunately it would also match things like `--helper-program`. I think the code is just buggy.

Answer (score 5):

You're right.

Moreover, the example you provided would match "--help" but also everything that begins with "--help" (like "--help-me").

A rare case in which overzealous == wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you're absolutely right--there's no reason to use strncmp instead of strcmp.  Perhaps people are just being overcautious (not necessarily a bad thing).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `strcmp()` is perfectly safe to use with literals. If you want to use `strncmp()`, try this:

```
strncmp(argv[i], "--help", sizeof("--help"))
```

Let the compiler do the counting for you!

This will only match the exact string "--help". If you want to match all strings which begin with `"--help"` (as your code does), use `sizeof() - 1` to not include the last `'\0'`.

Comment: you mean sizeof("--help") - 1, since sizeof will include the null terminator.

Comment: @Evan: depends on what you want to do - already edited my answer ;)

Comment: Then why use strncmp() in the first place? Much more verbose and redundant. Just use strcmp() if you only want to match the exact string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the presence of literal limits the size of compared data to the size of the literal. stncmp is redundant here.

Some may say that strncmp is a good habit to get into, but this is outweighted by the trouble of counting chars.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write something like this in C(if I was using strncmp a lot & didn't want to do character counting):

```
if(... strncmp(argv[i], "--help", sizeof("--help") - 1) == 0
```

Comment: but that iterates the string twice unnecessarily. At least use (sizeof("--help") - 1). And yes, sizeof works correctly on string literals since their size is known at compile time.

Comment: Also, no, strlen does not count the null.

Comment: I wasn't sure about sizeof against string literals. In general, I'd suggest C++ and std::string. :-)

Comment: the sizeof("--help") - 1 would match any string of any length that started with "--help", whereas just using sizeof("--help") INCLUDES the null terminator and will only match "--help".  That seems the more likely usage.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not done for safety. It could have been done to check only the start of command line parameter. Many programs just check the beginning of the command line switches and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

er... technically couldn't something like this happen?

```
char *cp1 = "help";
cp1[4] = '!'; // BAD PRACTICE! don't try to mutate a string constant!
// Especially if you remove the terminating null!
  ...
strcmp(some_variable, "help"); 
// if compiler is "smart" enough to use the same memory to implement
// both instances of "help", you are screwed...
```

I guess this is a pathological case and/or garbage-in, garbage out ("Doc, it hurts when I whack my head against the wall!" "Then don't do it!")...

(p.s. I'm just raising the issue -- if you feel this post muddies the waters, comment appropriately & I'll delete it)

Comment: Since the string modification is forbidden, I don't think you can say that other code is wrong because it is affected by it. It's like saying there's an error in one program because it can be executed by exploiting a buffer overflow in another.

Comment: If the two strings were stored in the same place, then the modification affects both strings, and the comparison will still be equal - or you get a core dump.  Of course, the behaviour is undefined; anything is possible - Google for 'nasal demons' if you like.

Comment: A program which does this is ill-formed, so as far as your program is concerned all logic ends there.